# The request failed with HTTP status 401: Access Denied

Tags: vb.net

I am new to Vb.net. I am creating an intranet application which needs the windows loginname. I got the login name from `System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials`. It worked fine in my localhost machine. But the problem is that when I am trying to access the site from Development server it is showing the error:

> The request failed with HTTP status 401: Access Denied

But the same code is working fine in Test environment.I don't have any idea why these both environment behaving differently.
I am using windows Integrated authentication and Anonymous access disabled. Please help me to figure out this issue.

```
Dim consumeWebService As ws-ProfileService
consumeWebService = New ws-ProfileService
consumeWebService.PreAuthenticate = True
consumeWebService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an impersonation issue.  Have a read here and see if this helps.  It's definitely worth the read even if seven years old.

[How To: Use Impersonation and Delegation in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998351.aspx)

Comment: Let me have a look on that site...Thanks Donny

Comment: I tried using <identity impersonate="true" /> in web.config file but now i am getting this error "500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed" @Donny McCoy

Comment: Are you logging into a domain and is the dev server on that domain too?

Comment: without giving <identity impersonate="true" /> also the code is working perfectly in QA environment so do you have any idea that there is any server based restrictions that will control the web service access in different environment servers(DEV,QA,Stage and Prod)..Because i figured out that only that web service is making the issue...@Donny McCoy

Comment: Best practice is to have servers in each environment as identical in configuration as possible.  So if it works in QA but not DEV, try to find the difference there.  I take it they are all on the same domain and authentication is configured the same?

Comment: I am not doing any  IIS settings so i contacted that team so they told like every settings are same in all environment.. I tried a try catch statement when calling the web service so in Dev environment it falls in catch but in QA environment it works fine...Can you please tell me what you meant by domain? @Donny McCoy

Comment: what statement in the TRY causes your code to drop into the CATCH?   By domain, I mean the network domain you log into.

Comment: Try Dim consumeWebService As ws.ProfileService
                consumeWebService = New ws.ProfileService
                consumeWebService.PreAuthenticate = True
                consumeWebService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials

                'CONTENT DISPLAY FOR TESTING
                Dim myResult As Data.DataTable
                myResult = consumeWebService.GetUserProfile(myUser)  End Try
Catch (I didn't include the whole code but think you will get some idea from this..) Thanks in advance for your time...

Comment: Ok thanks.  Which line of code triggers the exception and what is the error number?  that object is instantiated as EX inside your catch.

Comment: I am not able to figure out which line is making that exception because that code is working perfectly in my Local system ..But when i deployed the code in DEV it flows to catch but not in QA.@Donny McCoy

Comment: Are you able to add code in the catch to dump the exception properties to screen output and then halt the response with response.end?  Rudimentary but quick and dirty.  This still sounds like a config difference between servers...

Comment: I changed the version of the application frame work from 3.5 to 4.0 is that will make any difference to web service? @Donny McCoy